# Add $$hashKey to object in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The Angular-specific property on enumerated objects `$$hashKey`can be used for a lot of things.

For example DOM-targeting;

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in objects">
    <label for="field-{{obj.$$hashKey}}">
        Label
    </label>
    <input type="text" id="field-{{obj.$$hashKey}}" />
</div>
```

In some weird case I am experiencing now the $$hashKey prop is not yet set on a object I want to access it on even though it is being repeated with Angular.
Is there a way to set this property yourself when initializing the object?

Edit: My guess is that there is some form of execution order issue, that I access the property when Angular has yet to process the repetition.
I am deep watching an object, within that object is an array with objects which is getting repeated. It's also on one of those objects that I need to access the `$$hashKey` property on.

Simple example;

```
var MyController = function($scope, Obj)
{
    $scope.obj = {
        list: [obj, obj, obj, obj]
    };

    $scope.$watch("obj", function()
    {
        var lastObj = $scope.obj.list[$scope.obj.list.length - 1];
        console.log(lastObj.$$hashKey); // Undefined?
    }, true);

    $scope.addObj = function()
    {
        $scope.obj.list.push(new Obj());
    };
};
```

Edit2: jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2sbWp/2/

Comment: Please create a plunker or jsFiddle, it's difficult to replicate the problem you are experiencing

Comment: My question is pretty straightforward.

Replicating the problem will take time even for me as I have to strip out a lot of company-specific code which I can't display publicly.

Comment: I agree that it's straightforward, I'm not asking you to post company code, just to replicate the issue using dummy code.

Comment: Check my edit, I think that example should make it clearer on what is going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use $timeout with no delay value to defer until the $$hashKey property is available:

```
$timeout(function(){console.log(lastObj.$$hashKey)});
```

[A working fork of your Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marcolepsy/uLFcc/)

Comment: This seems to work as a charm! I am no longer at work so I can't confirm it's actually working, but I see no reason for it not to.

I will create an issue for this in Angulars issue-tracker though. I don't know if this is working as intended or if it's a bug and I don't know how deeply rooted it is in the latter case.

Comment: Might be worth exploring. I think though that you'll find it is expected behavior as you need to give Angular a chance to decorate your object with things like $$hashKey before accessing them. If you find out otherwise, it would be worthy of an update here.

Answer (score 0):

I created a dummy example based on you code, see here: http://plnkr.co/edit/9PNc6bcy1TO4Zaeyuvwq?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module( 'gssApp', [] );

app.controller( 'gssAppController', [ '$scope', '$http', function ( $scope, $http )
{
  var obj = {'hash': 'test'};
  $scope.newObject = {'hash': 'test'};
  $scope.model = null;

  $scope.objects = [];

  $scope.addObj = function(){
    if($scope.model !== null && $scope.model !== undefined){
      $scope.objects.push({'hash': $scope.model});
      $scope.model = '';
      angular.forEach($scope.objects, function(key, value){
        console.log(value, key);
      }); 
    }
  }; 

}] );
```

HTML

```
<body ng-app="gssApp" ng-controller="gssAppController">
    <div ng-repeat="obj in objects">
      <label for="field-{{obj.$$hashKey}}" ng-click="alert(obj.$$hashKey)">
         Label
      </label>
      <input type="text" id="field-{{obj.$$hashKey}}" />
    </div>
    <input type="text" placeholder='add new key' ng-model="model">
    <button ng-click="addObj();">Submit</button>
</body>
```

Hopefully this sheds some light on the $$hashkey

Comment: I am not getting any instances where $$hashkey is not set

Comment: Seems like the problem has more to do with his $watch and something specific to getHashKey(), which isn't expressed sufficiently in his sample code and is therefore hard to help with.

Comment: The `getHashKey` function in my example is just a dummy. Just pretend it reads the `$$hashKey` property.
Your code is not replicating my scenario one bit, it's also not an answer or a solution to my actual question.

I really don't know how to simplify the scenario more. It's as simple as it gets.

Comment: In regards to your question, you should set your own hashKey, with a different variable name so that you can utilize it, rather than relying on $$hashKey, if you really need a hash value

Comment: That is a really sub-par suggestion. I would rather patch it in Angular if it turns out it's a bug instead of doing ugly hacks.

I have now created a jsFiddle for my issue. If that's not clear enough I lose all my faith in humanity.

Comment: Not a bug (see my answer) and for the future, the sooner you can post a Fiddle or similar demonstrating a problem, the sooner you will tend to get an answer that directly addresses your problem without having to "cater to [the] idiots" (see: your edit) who are trying to help you.